# SSH-Keygen "no such file or directory"

Tags: git, powershell, ssh

Trying to Generate a public key for my git. Using Powershell.

```
PS>ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my@emailaddress.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (//.ssh/id_rsa):
Could not create directory '//.ssh': Read-only file system
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "//.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory
```

If I give a location for the file and run

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

It doesn't check the custom location for the public key to use

```
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [<<ANIPADDRESS>>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:<<SCAREDTOPUBLISH>>
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: FYI `ssh-add` does not resolve paths so `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` will not work.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The command could not save your key, likely because it was unable to determine your `$HOME` directory. Specify a file, at a location where you have write access:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my@emailaddress.com" -f /path/to/key
```

This will save your private key in `/path/to/key` and the public key in `/path/to/key.pub`.
When successful,
instead of an error message, you will see something like:

> ```
> Your identification has been saved in /path/to/key.
> Your public key has been saved in /path/to/key.pub.
> The key fingerprint is:
> 76:f7:82:04:1e:64:eb:9c:df:dc:0a:6b:26:73:1b:2c
> The key's randomart image is:
> +--[ RSA 2048]----+
> |        o        |
> |       o .       |
> |        +        |
> |       + +       |
> |        S o .    |
> |       . = = o   |
> |        E * + o  |
> |        o.++ o   |
> |         *o..    |
> +-----------------+
> ```

And then, to make `ssh` look for the file at the custom location,
use the `-i` flag:

```
ssh -i /path/to/key -vT git@github.com
```

---

Alternatively,
if you have an authentication agent running,
you can add your key to the agent with:

```
ssh-add /path/to/key
```

Once your key is stored by the agent, you can simply do:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

The response should look something like:

> ```
> Hi USER! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
> ```

And you can go ahead and clone your repository with:

```
git clone git@github.com:USER/REPO
```

Comment: I get an error: "**permission denied public key**".  You missed the step where you have to login to your Github page and add the id_rsa.pub key!

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I don't see how that's related to this question. I suggest to ask a new question about it, and make sure to include all necessary details, such as the commands you ran, and their complete output. Good luck.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky This question was specifically about a “no such file or directory” issue when using the `ssh-keygen` command. Not meant as a tutorial of authentication with GitHub, there are many other answers for that, as well as GitHub's own excellent documentation.

Comment: I get a `key_load_public: No such file or directory` error when it looks for `identity file /home/yuri/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1`

Comment: If working under linux: When you copy&paste the path from a file explorer (e.g. nautilus), "file://" gets appended to the beginning of the path. That's a reason why a path could not be found.

Comment: In my case I tried to pass a path relative to my home directory like `~/.ssh/foo` to `ssh-keygen` presuming the user would get expanded to my current user, however, it doesn't seem to support this.  Changing the path to absolute `/Users/myuser/.ssh/foo` does work.

Answer (score 10):

For me, the `ssh-keygen` command appears to fail only when using cmd:

> Your identification has been saved in [...]/.ssh/id_rsa.
> fdopen [...]/.ssh/id_rsa.pub failed: No such file or directory

The private key is generated, but the public key file is created with 0 bytes.

If I run the command in Git Bash on Windows, it works.

Answer (score 9):

This work for me: `ssh-add '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa'`

Comment: save me a day, many thank

Answer (score 3):

i tried this instead of `~/.ssh/whatever_file_name`

this code worked for me

```
ssh-add /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

replace `<user>` with your user folder name...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error: `Saving key "//.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory`

Seems to me like you need to create folder `.ssh`

Try `mkdir .ssh`, and then run `ssh-keygen -t rsa` again.

Answer (score -1):

work for me on Mac: `ssh-add /Users/your_user_name/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score -1):

For me, the username was wrong :) Can't believe that's simple :(